# Where does the Bible mention a "gold earring on the Ethiopian's cheek"

Tags: verse-identification

I can't find the proverb or scripture that mentions a "gold earring on the cheek of the Ethiopian." Am I having a false memory? What verse is it?

Comment: I can find six references (see Young's Analytical Concordance) to gold earrings. None are associated with an Ethiopian. There is one reference to Ishmaelites in Judges 8:24.

Comment: You might be thinking of Shakespeare: ["Like a rich jewel in an Ethiope’s ear"](https://www.sparknotes.com/nofear/shakespeare/romeojuliet/page_60/)

Comment: @curiousdanii, That has to be it. I remember clearly that it was a gold earring, but my memory must be wrong in this case. Add Romeo and Juliet as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Oh, she doth teach the torches to burn bright!
> It seems she hangs upon the cheek of night
> Like a rich jewel in an Ethiope’s ear,

From Romeo and Juliet.

Perhaps your memory combined this poem with the Bible account of the Ethiopian eunuch.

Even more Ike your memory is a modern English rendering:

> Oh, she shows the torches how to burn bright! She stands out against the darkness like a jeweled earring hanging against the cheek of an African.